# Unable to connect lavalink server to bot.py

Tags: discord.py

Hello im trying to host lavalink server on a repl.it but it is not connecting it says
`NODE-hongkong-la********.vnns.repl.co:443] The remote server returned code 400, the expected code was 101. This usually indicates that the remote server is a webserver and not Lavalink. Check your ports, and try again.`. I hope you can help me with my problem

This is my cogs.music

```
# cogs.music
class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
    self.bot.music.add_node('la********.vnns.repl.co', 443, 'test', 'hongkong', 'music-node')
    self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on_socket_response')
    self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)
```

Snippet of application.yml

```
server: 
  port: 443
  address: 0.0.0.0
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "test"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      mixer: true
      http: true
      local: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses
    frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The lavalink changed everything since, and I really don't recommend using lavalink, I used wavelink and it works completely fine(wavelink is an easier connection to lavalink servers).
If you want a full guide, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REAMABgpmcA).
After you watch that video, I have an upgraded code that added queue, song list, and stuff, use it in your music cog if you want to:

```
import discord
import wavelink
import typing
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        bot.loop.create_task(self.create_nodes())

    async def create_nodes(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot=self.bot, host="YOUR_ADRESS(Your adress shouldent be 0.0.0.0, do something like 127.0.0.1)", port="YOUR_PORT", password="youshallnotpass", region="asia")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("music cog ready! (beta)")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_node_ready(self, node: wavelink.Node):
        print(f"Node <{node.identifier}> ready!")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send(f"Unknown command")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_track_end(self, player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track, reason):
        ctx = player.ctx
        vc: player = ctx.voice_client

        if vc.loop:
            return await vc.play(track)
    
        if vc.queue.is_empty:
            return await ctx.send("The queue is empty")
    
        next_song = vc.queue.get()
        song = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=str(next_song), return_first=True)
        if not song.uri == None:
                ur = song.uri
        else:
            ur = "None"
        if not song.author == None:
            au = song.author
        else:
            au = "None"
        if song.is_stream():
            stream = "True"
        else:
            stream = "False"
        await vc.play(song)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Now Playing `{song.title}`", description=f"Info:\nSong length(second), {song.duration}\nAuthor, {au}\nLink, {ur}\nStream, {stream}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    

    @commands.command(name="join", aliases=["connect", "summon"], description="Join the voice channel you provided or the music channel you are in")
    async def join_commad(self, ctx, channel: typing.Optional[discord.VoiceChannel]):
        try:
            if channel is None:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        
            node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
            player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

            if player is not None:
                if player.is_connected():
                    return await ctx.send("bot is already connected to a voice channel")
        
            await channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Connected to {channel.name}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except AttributeError:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "quit"], description="Leave the Voice channel")
    async def leave_command(self, ctx):
        node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
        player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

        if player is None:
            return await ctx.send("bot is not connected to any voice channel")
    
        await player.disconnect()
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Disconnected", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name="play", description="search the music name you provided and play it")
    async def play_command(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("Join a voice channel first!")
        song = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=search, return_first=True)
    
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing():
            await vc.play(song)
            if not song.uri == None:
                ur = song.uri
            else:
                ur = "None"
            if not song.author == None:
                au = song.author
            else:
                au = "None"
            if song.is_stream():
                stream = "True"
            else:
                stream = "False"
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Now Playing `{song.title}`", description=f"Info:\nSong length(second), {song.duration}\nAuthor, {au}\nLink, {ur}\nStream, {stream}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(song)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Added `{song}` to the queue")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        vc.ctx = ctx
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)

    @commands.command(name="overrideplay", description="Play the music without adding it to the query and override all songs")
    async def overrideplay_command(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("Join a voice channel first!")
        song = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=search, return_first=True)
    
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if vc.queue.is_empty:
            await vc.play(song)
            if not song.uri == None:
                ur = song.uri
            else:
                ur = "None"
            if not song.author == None:
                au = song.author
            else:
                au = "None"
            if song.is_stream():
                stream = "True"
            else:
                stream = "False"
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Now Playing `{song.title}`", description=f"Info:\nSong length(second), {song.duration}\nAuthor, {au}\nLink, {ur}\nStream, {stream}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    else:
            await ctx.send("The queue is not empty, use the stop command to clear the queue!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        vc.ctx = ctx
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)

    @commands.command(name="stop", description="Finish the music(It will finish the music it is not resume if you want to play it again do rr?play <song name>)")
    async def stop_command(self, ctx):
        try:
            node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
            player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

            if player is None:
                return await ctx.send("Bot is not connected to any voice channel")
            else:
                vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        
            if player.is_playing:
                if not vc.queue.is_empty:
                    vc.queue.clear()
                    await player.stop()
                else:
                    await player.stop()
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Playback Stoped", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
                return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                return await ctx.send("Nothing is playing")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @commands.command(name="skip", description="Skip this song and move on to the next song if there is one")
    async def skip_command(self, ctx):
        node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
        player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

        if player is None:
            return await ctx.send("Bot is not connected to any voice channel")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if player.is_playing:
            await player.stop()
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Playback Skipped", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            return await ctx.send("Nothing is playing")

    @commands.command(name="pause", description="pause the music if it is playing one")
    async def pause_command(self, ctx):
        node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
        player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

        if player is None:
            return await ctx.send("Bot is not connected to any voice channel")
    
        if not player.is_paused():
            if player.is_playing():
                await player.pause()
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Playback Paused", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
                return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                return await ctx.send("Nothing is playing")
        else:
            return await ctx.send("Playback is Already paused")

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["continue"], description="resume the music if it is playing one")
    async def resume_command(self, ctx):
        node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
        player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

        if player is None:
            return await ctx.send("bot is not connected to any voice channel")
    
        if player.is_paused():
            await player.resume()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Playback resumed", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            return await ctx.send("playback is not paused")

    @commands.command(name="volume", description="Change the music volume between 1 and 100")
    async def volume_command(self, ctx, to:int):
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            return await ctx.send("I am not even in a voice channel!")
        if to > 100:
            return await ctx.send("Volume should be between 1 and 100")
        elif to < 1:
            return await ctx.send("Volume should be between 1 and 100")
    
        node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
        player = node.get_player(ctx.guild)

        await player.set_volume(to)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Changed volume to {to}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name="loop", description="Loop the music")
    async def loop_command(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            return await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel!")
        elif not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if vc.loop == False:
            vc.loop = True
        else:
            setattr(vc, "loop", False)
    
        if vc.loop:
            return await ctx.send("Loop is now **Enabled!**")
        else:
            return await ctx.send("Loop is now **Disabled!**")

    @commands.command(name="queue", description="Show the queue")
    async def queue_command(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            return await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel!")
        elif not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

        if vc.queue.is_empty:
            return await ctx.send("Queue is empty")
    
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Queue", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        queue = vc.queue.copy()
        song_count = 0
        for song in queue:
            song_count += 1
            embed.add_field(name=f"Song {song_count}", value=f"`{song}`")

        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name="info", description="search the music name you provided and show the info of it", aliases=["information"])
    async def info_command(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        song = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=search, return_first=True)
        if not song.uri == None:
            ur = song.uri
        else:
            ur = "None"
        if not song.author == None:
            au = song.author
        else:
            au = "None"
        if song.is_stream():
            stream = "True"
        else:
            stream = "False"
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Info about `{song.title}`", description=f"Info:\nSong length(second), {song.duration}\nAuthor, {au}\nLink, {ur}\nStream, {stream}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name="addsong", description="Add a song to your song list")
    async def addsong_command(self, ctx, *, song: str):
        try:
            so = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=song, return_first=True)
            so1 = str(so) + ", "
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT song_list FROM main WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO main(user_id, song_list) VALUES(?,?)")
                val = (ctx.author.id, so1)
                await ctx.send(f"First song added! {so}")
            elif result is not None:
                sfinal = result[0] + (so1)
                sql = ("UPDATE main SET song_list = ? WHERE user_id = ?")
                val = (sfinal, ctx.author.id,)
                await ctx.send(f"Song has been added: {so}")
            cursor.execute(sql, val)
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(e)

    @commands.command(name="mysonglist", description="Show your song list")
    async def mysonglist_command(self, ctx):
        try:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT song_list FROM main WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
                return await ctx.send("You don't have any song in your list")
            elif result is not None:
                result = " ".join(result)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Your song list", description=f"{result}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 255, 255))
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(e)

    @commands.command(name="deletesonglist", description="Delete your song list")
    async def deletesonglist_command(self, ctx):
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT song_list FROM main WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            try:
                sql = ("DELETE FROM main WHERE user_id = ?")
                val = (ctx.author.id,)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                await ctx.send("Sucessfully removed your song list")
            except Exception as e:
                await ctx.send(e)
        elif result is None:
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
            return await ctx.send("You don't have a song list!")
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Also I saw that your application.yml is a bit weird, here is what it should look like(Change the password, **DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ELSE**):

```
server: 
  port: 443
  address: 127.0.0.1
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "password"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      mixer: true
      http: true
      local: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses
    frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""

logging:
  file:
    max-history: 30
    max-size: 1GB
  path: ./logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: INFO
```